# What is the point of this computation? (Restriction of the Hessian to the normal bundle.)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

This is from Banyaga & Hurtubise, Lectures on Morse Theory:

[image]

Why do the authors say

> *Therefore*, the Hessian induces a symmetric bilinear form... ?

Isn't this form just obtained by restriction to the subspace $\nu_p C$? Why do we need to check something in order to "induce" this form?

Comment: I was a little confused about this too. IIRC I decided their actual point was that it descended to a bilinear form on the normal bundle $TM/TC$; this can be defined without using a metric to pick out an orthogonal complement. In particular the bilinear form didn't depend on the metric (which, of course, is important).

Comment: @MikeMiller Indeed, it seems like a sensible explanation.